# Altair/Streamlit not reading column name for multiline chart

Tags: python, altair, streamlit

I have dataframe with column names that are in the form of `'State1 - City - 1-1'`, `'State1 - City - 1-2'` ....etc. When I run the streamlit code: `st.line_chart(df)`, I get the error:

> ValueError: variable encoding field is specified without a type; the
> type cannot be inferred because it does not match any column in the
> data

For testing purposes, if I change all column names to integers, I get the desired chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see this error, it means that the column names used in your chart do not match the column names in your dataframe. In your case, I suspect this may be caused by using different types of hyphens. For example:

```python
>>> 'State1 - City - 1-1' == 'State1 – City – 1-1'
False
```

The `'-'` characters in the first string are hyphens, while the `'–'` characters in the second string are em dashes; though they appear similarly in some fonts, they are not equivalent.

Make certain the field names in your chart exactly match the column names in your data.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I completely removed spaces and '-' and it still failed. I am not explicitly specifying columns to plot, it is a multiline plot so I expected it to plot all columns. I have a load_data() function and the output is passed straight to st.line_chart(df)

Comment: Also, I should add, st.dataframe(df) works works

Comment: Fixed. My pivot table had a column index with a name. Removing the column index name fixed it.

Comment: I had to explicitly assign column names as strings (even though they were strings before) for plot to work - df.columns = [str(col) for col in df.columns]